# Python pandas: replace values based on location not index value

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my df:

```
In[12]: df  = pd.DataFrame(data = list("aabbcc"), columns = ["s"], index=range(11,17))
In[13]: df
Out[13]: 
    s
11  a
12  a
13  b
14  b
15  c
16  c
```

Let's try to replace values based on index:

```
In[14]: df.loc[11, "s"] = 'A'
In[15]: df
Out[15]: 
    s
11  A
12  a
13  b
14  b
15  c
16  c
In[16]: df.ix[12, "s"] = 'B'
In[17]: df
Out[17]: 
    s
11  A
12  B
13  b
14  b
15  c
16  c
```

It works! But if I do the same based on position, not index, say something like this, but it shows ValueError (`ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]`):

```
In[18]: df.iloc[1, "s"] = 'b'
```

And, if I try something like this:

```
df.s.iloc[1] = "b"
```

I get this warning :

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Comment: The  first error you are getting is because you are trying to use integer based indexing with a string. try `df.iloc[1, 0] = 'b'`. Is this the full code that you are running? `df.s.iloc[1] = "b"` does not produce an error when I run it. I would expect to see the warning you are getting if `df` was created by slicing another dataframe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use get_loc to get the location of the column and pass that to iloc:

```
df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('s')] = 'B'

df
Out: 
    s
11  a
12  B
13  b
14  b
15  c
16  c
```

Or the other way around:

```
df.loc[df.index[1], 's'] = 'B'
```

Comment: I fail to understand the design of this behavior. Why would it make sense to force the user to provide the index of a named column by an extra function call?