# Change row values based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> BA_df
                   'BID_price' 'ASK_price'
2017-06-01-09:30   100.00      101.50
2017-06-01-09:35   102.00      101.80
2017-06-01-09:40   101.65      101.82
```

What I would like to do is make both rows equal to zero if the `BID_price` is greater than, or equal to, the `ASK_price`. Otherwise, leave everything as it is. [I checked out this question, which uses numpy.select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119047/pandas-dataframe-change-a-value-based-on-column-index-values-comparison), but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Filter and `reindex`

```
df=df.query('BID_price<=ASK_price').reindex(df.index,fill_value=0)
df
Out[724]: 
                  BID_price  ASK_price
2017-06-01-09:30     100.00     101.50
2017-06-01-09:35       0.00       0.00
2017-06-01-09:40     101.65     101.82
```

Or `where` (`mask`)

```
df=df.where(df.BID_price<=df.ASK_price,0)
df
Out[726]: 
                  BID_price  ASK_price
2017-06-01-09:30     100.00     101.50
2017-06-01-09:35       0.00       0.00
2017-06-01-09:40     101.65     101.82
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks simple when you know how :p

Comment: @scrps93 yep . it is :-) happy coding